# Newbie with Spring MVC, correct usage

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud, master-detail

I'm starting with web development and Spring MVC.

I currently have a good knowledge about create a simple CRUD.

But now, I need to do something more advanced.
I need to create a CRUD to an entity with details, like a Invoice with items/products.

What is the best way to manage this CRUD without persist the Invoice with no items?

How can I persist the entity only when the user ends to enter the fully data (invoice + items) ?

How will be the Controller to do this?

I already found this [Explain this Spring MVC Controller behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520837/explain-this-spring-mvc-controller-behavior), but it doesn't clarify my questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beto, have a look at the [spring.io/guides](http://spring.io/guides) page for clear examples of how to do this.

Especially review the 3 big tutorials at bottom of page (best one is http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/).

That will give you good answers and explanations behind them.